# Could not execute server name along with query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I try to execute the below query it shown an error

```
Select * from [Domain].[Database Name].dbo.tblUser
```

Error:

> Could not find server 'Domain' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, if you wish to connect from one SQL Server to another, you need to add the other server as a linked server.

See the definition for [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) for how to do this.